# Python - Regular Expression For Domain Names

Tags: python, regex, url, dns

I am trying use the following regular expression to extract domain name from a text, but it just produce nothing, what's wrong with it?

I don't know if this is suitable to ask this "fix code" question, maybe I should read more.

I just want to save some time.

Thanks.

```
pat_url = re.compile(r'''

            (?:https?://)*

            (?:[\w]+[\-\w]+[.])*

            (?P<domain>[\w\-]*[\w.](com|net)([.](cn|jp|us))*[/]*)

            ''')

print re.findall(pat_url,"http://www.google.com/abcde")
```

I want the output to be **google.com**.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use regex for this. Use the `urlparse` standard library instead. It's far more straightforward and easier to read/maintain.

http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

Comment: thanks Dav, but the urlparse.netloc returns "www.google.com" ? And I want to extract urls in text like
<a href = "http://www.google.com/adfaskl">
?

Comment: urlparse.scheme + urlparse.netloc + urlparse.path should give you the expected result.

Comment: Maybe everyone else knows this, but urlparse.netloc is a member var, not a function. Example: `p=urlparse.urlparse(url) ; print p.netloc` prints `host.example.com`

Comment: `urlparse.netloc` is not necessarily a domain name.  it could be an IP address or non-domain word.  you might want to grab `http://localhost`, but a typo like `http://example_com` would also pass.

Answer (score 3):

The first is that you're missing the `re.VERBOSE` flag in the call to `re.compile()`. The second is that you should use the methods on the returned object. The third is that you're using a regular expression where an appropriate parser already exists in the stdlib.

Comment: oh.. the re.VERBOSE WORKS. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the only correct way to parse an url with a regex:

It's in C++ but you'll find trivial to convert to python by removing additional \. And with an enum for the captures.

Also see RFC3986 as original source for the regexp.

```
static const char* const url_regex[] = {
    /* RE_URL */
    "^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*)|///)?([^?#]*)(\\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?",
};

enum {
    URL = 0,
    SCHEME_CLN = 1,
    SCHEME  = 2,
    DSLASH_AUTH = 3,
    AUTHORITY = 4,
    PATH    = 5,
    QUERY   = 6,
    FRAGMENT = 7
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9])\.(COMMUNITY|DIRECTORY|EDUCATION|EQUIPMENT|INSTITUTE|MARKETING|SOLUTIONS|XN--J1AMH|XN--L1ACC|BARGAINS|BOUTIQUE|BUILDERS|CATERING|CLEANING|CLOTHING|COMPUTER|DEMOCRAT|DIAMONDS|GRAPHICS|HOLDINGS|LIGHTING|PARTNERS|PLUMBING|TRAINING|VENTURES|XN--P1AI|ACADEMY|CAREERS|COMPANY|CRUISES|DOMAINS|EXPOSED|FLIGHTS|FLORIST|GALLERY|GUITARS|HOLIDAY|KITCHEN|RECIPES|RENTALS|REVIEWS|SHIKSHA|SINGLES|SUPPORT|SYSTEMS|AGENCY|BERLIN|CAMERA|CENTER|COFFEE|CONDOS|DATING|ESTATE|EVENTS|EXPERT|FUTBOL|KAUFEN|LUXURY|MAISON|MONASH|MUSEUM|NAGOYA|PHOTOS|REPAIR|REPORT|SOCIAL|TATTOO|TIENDA|TRAVEL|VIAJES|VILLAS|VISION|VOTING|VOYAGE|BUILD|CARDS|CHEAP|CODES|DANCE|EMAIL|GLASS|HOUSE|NINJA|PARTS|PHOTO|SHOES|SOLAR|TODAY|TOKYO|TOOLS|WATCH|WORKS|AERO|ARPA|ASIA|BIKE|BLUE|BUZZ|CAMP|CLUB|COOL|COOP|FARM|GIFT|GURU|INFO|JOBS|KIWI|LAND|LIMO|LINK|MENU|MOBI|MODA|NAME|PICS|PINK|POST|QPON|RICH|RUHR|SEXY|TIPS|WANG|WIEN|ZONE|BIZ|CAB|CAT|CEO|COM|EDU|GOV|INT|KIM|MIL|NET|ONL|ORG|PRO|RED|TEL|UNO|WED|XXX|AC|AD|AE|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AN|AO|AQ|AR|AS|AT|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BJ|BM|BN|BO|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CC|CD|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|CL|CM|CN|CO|CR|CU|CV|CW|CX|CY|CZ|DE|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EC|EE|EG|ER|ES|ET|EU|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|GA|GB|GD|GE|GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|ID|IE|IL|IM|IN|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MG|MH|MK|ML|MM|MN|MO|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NC|NE|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NU|NZ|OM|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|ST|SU|SV|SX|SY|SZ|TC|TD|TF|TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TN|TO|TP|TR|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UK|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|YE|YT|ZA|ZM|ZW)(?![-0-9a-z])(?!\.[a-z0-9])
> ```

This Regex uses all current valid TLDs found http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt it will take a list of text and only return the `domain.tld`

Eg. Feed it

- http://google.com
- www.hotmail.com
- yahoo.net

Will return

- google.com
- hotmail.com
- yahoo.net

This isn't ideal, as the regex is quite long but it worked for what I needed at the time, hope it was helpful.