# Get domain from string? - Python

Tags: python, string, url, dns

i needed help. How do i get domain from a string?

For example: "*Hi im Natsume, check out my site http://www.mysite.com/*"

How do i get just **mysite.com**?

Output example:

http://www.mysite.com/ (if http entered)

www.mysite.com  (if http not entered)

mysite.com (if both http and www not entered)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626995/python-regular-expression-for-domain-names)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you thought about searching the string for certain defining characteristics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myString = "Hi im Natsume, check out my site http://www.mysite.com/"
>>> a = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", myString) or re.search("(?P<url>www[^\s]+)", myString)
>>> a.group("url")
'http://www.mysite.com/'
>>> myString = "Hi im Natsume, check out my site www.mysite.com/"
>>> a = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", myString) or re.search("(?P<url>www[^\s]+)", myString)
>>> a.group("url")
'www.mysite.com/'
```

Comment: Ok now i how to get the URL, if user didnt enter http? I mean it can accept either if http is entered or not, and also if www is entered or not entered either

Comment: @Nastume use re.search("(?P<url>www[^\s]+)", myString).group("url")

Comment: hmm it still unable to accept if user didnt enter either http or www either :(

Comment: @Nastume can give me an example input and output for your case

Comment: so far i can only do this re.search("(?P<url>(https?|www)[^\s]+)", a).group("url") but still unable to accept if http or www not entered

Comment: @Nastume without http and www it is difficult to identify the url pattern as url can end in .in,.nl,.co,.com,.co.uk,.org,.gov and so on

Answer (score 1):

Well ... You need some way to define what you consider to be something that *has* a "domain". One approach might be to look up a regular expression for URL-matching, and apply that to the string. If that succeeds, you at least know that the string holds a URL, and can continue to interpret the URL in order to look for a host name, from which you can then extract the domain (possibly).

Answer (score 1):

If all the sites had the same format, you could use a regexp like this (which work in this specific case):

```
re.findall('http://www\.(\w+)\.com', url)
```

However you need a more complex regexp able to parse whichever url and extract the domain name.

Comment: if domain have structure like this, my-web-site.com (\w+) find just "site"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regular expression, one way could be -

```
>>> s = "Hi im Natsume, check out my site http://www.mysite.com/"
>>> re.findall(r'http\:\/\/www\.([a-zA-Z0-9\.-_]*)\/', s)
['mysite.com']
```

..considering url ends with '/'

Comment: Ahh i like your code a bit. But how to get the domain if the user didnt enter http:// or www?

Comment: In that case, you can simply do -
`>>> s = "Hi im Natsume, check out my site mysite.com"
>>> [t for t in s.split() if '.com' in t]
['mysite.com']`

Comment: the regex i modified -> raw = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)([a-zA-Z0-9\/]*)', url),  im tyring to make the regex to find domain if http:// or www is entered or not, and either the url is at the beginning, end, or in the middle of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
s= "Hi im Natsume, check out my site http://www.mysite.com/"
start=s.find("http://") if s.find("http://")!=-1 else s.find("https://")+1
t = s[start+11:s.find(" ",start+11)]
print(t)
```

**output:**
`mysite.com`

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use regex to extract the URL. Then use `tldextract` to get valid domain name from the URL.

```
import re
import tldextract

text = "Hi im Natsume, check out my site http://www.example.com/"
urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', text)
found_url = urls[0]
info = tldextract.extract(found_url)
domain_name = info.domain
suffix_name = info.suffix
final_domain_name  = domain_name+"."+suffix_name
print(final_domain_name)
```

Comment: @user_3pij check out the mods I've made. URL is in capitals and not in highlight because its not a method or code in this case. Once you've seen them flag this comment for removal.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

url='https://www.google.com/'

var=url.split('//www.')[1]

domain=var[0:var.index('/')]

print(domain)

Comment: Read the question carefully. There may be different scenarios, including one where `www` is not in the input string at all.